# Impact of changing GSuite primary domain on existing Google Drive oauth credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

Our company is changing its branding and getting a new domain, which we plan on making the primary domain in GSuite.

We are concerned of potential unintended consequences.

In particular, our app connects to our users Google Drive and Google Sheets accounts via a project we created in the Google Developer Console.

Will changing our primary domain invalidate the existing credentials that our app uses to connect to our customers Google Drive / Sheets?

Are there any other potential unintended consequences?

Comment: The OAuth Client Secrets in your Google Cloud Project are independent from G Suite. However, if you change your domain name in G Suite and reissue email addresses for users, then the permissions that these users had will be gone as they will be using a new identity. The old identities will still work, provided that you keep those identities in G Suite. The ability to change your G Suite primary domain depends on the type of G Suite account that you have. Read these links: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en AND https://support.google.com/a/answer/54819?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I saw these but nothing related to the impact to API tokens specifically. Is there a way we can test it somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by API tokens?

Comment: The access tokens that we use to access the Google Drive API.

Comment: Google OAuth Access Tokens are only valid for 3,600 seconds (one hour). Since the tokens are issued using an identity, if you delete that identity, I am not sure what happens to the OAuth Refresh Token. I believe they are revoked, but I am not sure. The question comes down to how you are managing the switch over. If you are moving everyone to a new identity (email address) and deleting the old identities, the old identities will stop working, including any outstanding OAuth tokens once they expire.

Comment: I do not recommend trying to switch domains and have outstanding API requests still work. Plan for downtime and things not working with the old identities. If you plan to keep the old and new domains, then the old identities will continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just did the switch and it caused no problem and the existing oauth tokens remained valid.
Phew...